# Python/Doctest - doctesting complex strings

Tags: python, doctest

I'm a student working on an assignment where I'm supposed to doctest all internal functions. My functions use complex strings and return complex strings as well, so I have no idea how to do it. For example my function "ProcessImports()" can take the string:

```
%@import
blahblah
%@
```

And return:

```
\begin{shadedquoteBlueBar}
\fontsize{9pt}{9pt}
\begin{Verbatim}
blahblah}
\end{Verbatim}
\end{shadedquoteBlueBar}
\noindent
```

How would I go around doctesting this? I've not seen any examples of using doctest that don't return classes/structs or numbers or other simple representations ("\n" doesn't seem to work, for example).

Here's the function ProcessImports():
http://pastebin.com/3JjnyKjK

Any help would be appreciated!

Edit: might wanna ignore the attempted doctest at the top. That's just me trying to mess around to find out if I can make it work and failing horribly at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following example shows one successful approach; bear in mind that the doctest just needs to "look like" an interpreter session:

```
from textwrap import dedent

def function(s):
    """Testing doctests.

    >>> print function('''%@import
    ... blahblah
    ... %@''')
    <BLANKLINE>
    \\begin{shadedquoteBlueBar}
    \\fontsize{9pt}{9pt}
    \\begin{Verbatim}
    blahblah}
    \\end{Verbatim}
    \\end{shadedquoteBlueBar}
    \\noindent

    """
    s = dedent(r"""
               \begin{shadedquoteBlueBar}
               \fontsize{9pt}{9pt}
               \begin{Verbatim}
               blahblah}
               \end{Verbatim}
               \end{shadedquoteBlueBar}
               \noindent""")
    return s
```

Note the continuation characters `...` on the input to the function within the docstring.

Comment: But "function()" is supposed to take a string parameter, which is a complex string (the first code block in the question. Look at the linked source code to see what I mean). How would I do that?

Comment: I tried that, but it doesn't work :/ Here's what I've written: [link](http://pastebin.com/HCuJFa67) I get the message "ValueError: line 16 of docstring for Prepro.ProcessImports lacks blank after >>>: ">>>ProcessImports('''%@import"

Comment: @user2875994 the error message is pretty clear about the problem - note the space in my docstring between `>>>` and `print`.

Comment: Bork. Yeah, that fixed that error. Now I get "SyntaxError: EOF while scanning triple-quoted string literal". after %@import. I then tried adding the "..."'s you had (thought they weren't actually part of the code), but then it tells me I lack a blank after the "blahblah" bit, which I've tried to add (but I still get the same message).

Comment: @user2875994 how are you running these tests? I have saved the above code verbatim as `so.py`, and in the interpreter can run `import doctest, so` then `doctest.testmod(so)` with no issues (`TestResults(failed=0, attempted=1)`).

Comment: Oh I had to indent it in as well, now I'm getting somewhere. Thanks. Now I actually get to the part where they compare the strings. The problem now is that it says it expected a string that is displayed with actual newlines, while the string it compares it to is one long string with "\n"'s, and it fails.

Comment: @user2875994 yes, that's why I `print` the output of the function, which has the other advantage of shortening the line lengths. Please look more closely at the example I have provided, as many of these issues are already addressed.

Comment: I just had to remove the <BLANKLINE> and apply it to my code and it worked. Thanks! Sorry for the rush, I'm just at the last day of the assignment and I got stuck in this problem which is the last one i have to solve before I've finished the assignment >_> I would recommend moving the "..." explanation above the code-block, as it was easy to miss.

Comment: So I've implemented several doctests using this, and whenever anyone of them fails, it detects it. So in that respect it works wonderfully. One problem (?), though. If several tests fail, it just tells me that one fails. E.g. it seems to only find up to one error. If I fix the one that it tells me failed, then run the test again, it'll tell me another one that originally also failed is now the only failing one. And it'll continue like that until every single error is fixed. Shouldn't it display all the errors at once in one test?

Comment: Have you read [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/doctest.html)? There are options to display all tests or just the first fail.

Comment: To add to what I say, I'm using the --doctest-module of py.test, as I'm also using that (we're told to use it in the assignment). I've tried googling it, but it doesn't really give me anything to look into except [this](http://pytest.org/latest/doctest.html).